# How to pass in custom parameter for running tests on particular env

Tags: testing, automated-tests, ui-automation, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am running my tests using - `.testcaferc.json` file and command that I am using to run is : `node node_modules/testcafe/bin/testcafe`

I want to pass an additional parameter for running my different tests on different environments. When I tried to add that parameter in command:  `node node_modules/testcafe/bin/testcafe production` then I am not able to it as it consider them as tests.

Please let me know how can I handle this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the environment variables for this case.

Set the environment variable

```js
// Enviroment variable set is platform specific
// See https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/configuration/access-environment-variables-in-tests.html#set-environment-variables

export production=true

testcafe chrome test.js
```

and use it in a test

```js
fixture ('Fixture');

test('test', async t => {
   console.log(process.env.production);
});
```